# Not allowed to load local resource(видео). ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Есть такой код:

```html
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="@Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/preview.mp4")" type="video\mp4">
</video>
```

при нажатии на F12(chrome) в консоли я вижу: Not allowed to load local resource и путь к файлу.

А есть вот такой код:

```html
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
      <source src='@Url.Content("~/App_Data/preview.mp4")' type="video\mp4">
</video>
```

Он ошибки не выдает, но и видео на странице не отображается.

С самими видео никаких проблем нет, пробовал делать source url'ом на другое видео - воспроизводит нормально, а с локальной папки не хочет. Помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали в чате, что папка App_Data недоступна для чтения снаружи(то есть она доступна, но с определенными правами). Поэтому, создав папку Videos и указав вот такой источник,

```
'@Url.Content("~/Videos/preview.mp4")'
```

все прекрасно заработало.